# What command would I issue in order to complete this question?

Tags: shell, command-line

So I have tried over 10 different attempts and I'm just stumped

Here are two inverted-tree diagrams. Issue a command to change the left diagram to the right diagram. Assume that you are in your home directory and use relative pathnames. [home] is your home directory:

Here is the diagram:

```
         [home]                                          [home]
           |                                               |
     +----------+----------+                      +-------------+
     |          |          |                      |             | 
systems       ideas     courses                  ideas       courses
     |                                                          |
    notes                                                     systems
                                                                |
                                                              notes
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
mv system courses/system
mv [home] home
mv [home] [home]
mv [home]/courses/ideas/systems/notes [home]/ideas/courses/system/notes
```

and many more.. any ideas?

I'm using SSH Secure Shell to do this by the way.

Comment: No, we will not answer your test questions for you.

Comment: @John in this case, the OP has at least tried.

Comment: @terdon Yes, and I give him/her credit for the attempt, but it still smells way too much like a homework / test question.

Comment: Starting from your home directory you want to move the 'systems' directory into the 'courses' directory? - Just do that.

Comment: The command `mv` moves files or directories from one place to another in the filesystem tree. It's one of the most basic command and us answering your question wouldn't help you a bit. If you don't understand this by yourself, I suspect the rest of the questions will be very hard for you.

Comment: It's question 7 in the UNX122 course run by David Ward at Seneca College some years ago: https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~david.ward/unx122/notes/Lab3_Summary_031.html

Comment: @John [homework is not off topic](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/344/222220) as long as the OP has put some effort into it.

Comment: @terdon Ok, I'll update my policy to the linked one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to move the `systems` directory into the `courses` directory. Just:

```
mv systems courses/
```

Comment: uhg, it was that easy, huh. thank you.